# How would I make a command and someone uses it it detects if they put a restricted word in the restricted word list it runs `print("Language")`?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a command and someone uses it, it detects if they put a restricted word in the restricted word list it runs print("Language") below is the code I tried:

```
 @bot.command()
async def order(ctx, food):
    "This is to make an order to the kitchen, just say d.cook (food) to order"
    await ctx.message.delete
    kitchen = bot.get_channel(806579906095874088)
    waitEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Getting food to the kitchen", description=f"Your order has been placed of {food}, it will be out shortly :)", color=0xA52A2A)
    waitEmbed.add_field(name="From:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.mention}", inline=True)
    orderSendEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Cook food", description=f"Chefs! Cook {food}.", color=0x00ff00)
    orderSendEmbed.add_field(name="Food for:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.mention}", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=waitEmbed)
    await kitchen.send(embed=orderSendEmbed)
    print(f"{ctx.message.author}, used the order command in {ctx.message.channel} and ordered {food}.")
    for word in ctx.message.content:
        if word in RestrictedWords.RestrictedWordsList:
            print("Language!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) when iterating over the message content:

```py
@bot.command()
async def order(ctx, food):
    "This is to make an order to the kitchen, just say d.cook (food) to order"
    await ctx.message.delete()
    kitchen = bot.get_channel(<channel_id>)
    waitEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Getting food to the kitchen", description=f"Your order has been placed of {food}, it will be out shortly :)", color=0xA52A2A)
    waitEmbed.add_field(name="From:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.mention}", inline=True)
    orderSendEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Cook food", description=f"Chefs! Cook {food}.", color=0x00ff00)
    orderSendEmbed.add_field(name="Food for:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.mention}", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=waitEmbed)
    await kitchen.send(embed=orderSendEmbed)
    print(f"{ctx.message.author}, used the order command in {ctx.message.channel} and ordered {food}.")
    for word in ctx.message.content.lower().split():
        if word in ['foo', 'bar']: # Replace with your all lowercase RestrictedWordsList
            print('Language!')
```

It will split the string at each whitespace and return a list of words which you can iterate. This command prints `Language!` for each restricted word found in the content. Using `lower()` before `split()` makes the check case insensitive.

Without split(), the for loop would iterate over each character in the message.

Comment: It didn't work. I didn't get an error but when I put it at the bottom the entire command didn't work. Any way of fixing this?

Comment: You'd do
```
for word in ctx.message.content.split(" "):
    if word in RestrictedWords.RestrictedWordsList:
        print("Language!")
```
That didn't work because it was searching characters, not words.

Comment: `split(" ")` would split at each space character while `split()` removes all whitespace. I updated my answer to show the working command, I also added `lower()` before `split()` to detect words like `FoO`.